# The method name must start with either findBy, findOneBy, countBy

Tags: symfony

I've got a command tryng to access a repository method. But I can't succeed.

> services.yml

```
app.command.app_checkOfferDemand:
    class: AppRefactoredBundle\Command\CheckOfferAndDemand
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
    tags:
        - { name: console.command }
```

> app_OfferRepository

```
class app_OfferRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    private function checkAndUpdate(){
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $q = $qb->update('app_Offer', 'o')
            ->set('o.status_id', 2)
            ->where('o.createdAt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)')
            ->getQuery();
        return  $q->execute();
    }
}
```

> CheckOfferAndDemand

```
class CheckOfferAndDemand extends Command{

private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->em=$em;
}

protected function configure()
{
    // On set le nom de la commande
    $this->setName('app:check_OfferDemand');

    // On set la description
    $this->setDescription("Permet de controler le timeout des offres et demandes");

    // On set l'aide
    $this->setHelp("Cette commande ne prend pas d'argument et travailler sur toutes les offres et demandes");
}

public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){
    $output->writeln("update des offres");
    $this->em->getRepository('AppRefactoredBundle:app_Offer')->checkAndUpdate();
    $output->writeln("update des demandes");
    $this->em->getRepository('AppRefactoredBundle:app_Demand')->checkAndUpdate();
    $this->em->flush();
    $output->writeln("DONE");

   }
}
```

The command by itself is working (the first update print is made).
But then the error is triggered

> Undefined method 'checkAndUpdate'. The method name must start with either findBy, findOneBy or countBy!

The entities seems to be well declared too

```
/**
 * app_Offer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="app__offer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppRefactoredBundle\Repository\app_OfferRepository")
 */
class app_Offer
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Repository method cannot be accessed because it's denoted as `private`.

Change

```
private function checkAndUpdate() {
```

to

```
public function checkAndUpdate() {
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand why we can't access a private method throught his object like in java for example. But I will remind this.